# Data types for member's table?

Tags: java, mysql, types

What are the best data types to use for a members table and scores table on a mysql database?

I am creating a game in Java which connects to a hosted mysql database. I am unsure of which data types to use for each of the fields.

The fields I have are:

`TABLE tMembers`

```
ID INT(11)
firstName VARCHAR(255)
lastName VARCHAR(255)
email VARCHAR(255)
username VARCHAR(255)
password VARCHAR(255)
```

`TABLE tScores`

```
ID INT(11)
SCORE INT(11)
DATE DATETIME
```

I have heard a few things on SO and just form googling about the efficiency of using `VARCHAR(80)` for emails etc as emails cannot be longer than this, is this true?

For names, is `varchar` better than `text` (as a name cannot contain numbers or symbols, why not just use `text`?)

Also, for the `ID`, should I use `INT` or `INTEGER`?

Any help is more than appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have heard a few things on SO and just form googling about the
>   efficiency of using VARCHAR(80) for emails etc as emails cannot be
>   longer than this, is this true?

yes, if you define a column as varchar(x), the length of the value you want to save into that column should smaller than x.

> For names, is varchar better than text (as a name cannot contain
>   numbers or symbols, why not just use text?)

varchar contains (Max length) less characters than text, depends on the mysql version you are using. e.g. 5.03+ varchar can contain 65535 characters. but for your requirement, a varchar type for "names" would be ok.

> Also, for the ID, should I use INT or INTEGER?

as far as my understanding, the INT and INTEGER in mysql are the same. check
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html
there you can see:

> MySQL supports all standard SQL numeric data types. These types
>   include the exact numeric data types (INTEGER, SMALLINT, DECIMAL, and
>   NUMERIC), as well as the approximate numeric data types (FLOAT, REAL,
>   and DOUBLE PRECISION). **The keyword INT is a synonym for INTEGER**, and
>   the keywords DEC and FIXED are synonyms for DECIMAL.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I was on the right lines but not entirely sure.